# Downloaded SDKtool for Android on Windows but it won't run

Tags: android, windows

I have downloaded the latest SDKTools from the Android studio website, and installed the latest JDK (v 10).

I did restart and tried to run `android.bat` but it just open a window and then close it, instead than running the sdk tool updater app.

How do I fix this? So far I was able to deploy for Android devices only if I install the whole Android studio; but since I need it just for Unity; I am trying to run just the sdktools,but I have no luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

So, after searching for quite a while, the answer is simple: the new tools do not support newer Java JDK, so the only one that works is JDK8.

Quite a fascinating thing to develop for Android, if nobody even bother to add on the download readme, the little detail about dependencies on JDK versions :)